# How do I write something on a page that I have included in Latex using \includepdf?

Tags: package, latex, document, tex, overleaf

I included a pdf page on my document (using the pdfpages package) and I want to type on the page that I have included. How do I go about this?

I was able to insert the page number on the page using pagecommand but I do not know how to insert any other text.

Comment: Please add a  compilable [mre] and also make a sketch how the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can add text using `\usepackage{textpos}`

An example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={
    \begin{textblock}{5}(1,1)  %adjust width and absolute position.
        HELLO WORLD!
    \end{textblock}
}]{includeyourpage.pdf}

\end{document}
```